# Get peak amount of active rows from all time

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the following problem. I have a mysql table that has a startdate and and enddate. Each row is considered *active* between those dates. Some rows are no longer active, but have been active in the past. For example the following table:

```
id start                end
1  2014-11-11 00:00:00  2015-01-31 23:59:59
2  2014-09-25 10:16:14  2015-06-01 23:59:59
3  2013-12-24 00:00:00  2014-12-01 23:59:59
4  2014-08-13 00:00:00  2016-01-31 23:59:59
5  2013-09-11 00:00:00  2014-09-10 23:59:59
```

My actual table has way more data than that. Now I need to know what the peak amount of concurrent active rows is without knowing when that peak actually occured. How would I do this in SQL? In the example 4 rows are active at the same time (1-4, not 5) in the time between 2014-11-11 and 2015-01-31 23:59:59. The actual peak time doesn't matter to me as much as the peak amount itself.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find different timestamps of interrest using UNION ALL, count number of active tasks at these timestamps:

```
select ts, (select count(*) from tablename t2
            where timestamps.ts between t2.start and t2.end) as count
from (select start as ts
      from tablename
      union all
      select end
      from tablename) as timestamps
order by count desc
limit 1
```

Finally order descending and pick the highest value only!

(From a non MySQL user, so some details may be wrong... Please comment if that's the case and I'll edit!)